# Is grid the right layout for mobile web applications?

Tags: mobile, web-app, layout

Suppose you are creating a web application which supposed to work on mobile platforms like Android or iPhone, and one of the features of your app is to give the user an interface for adding, viewing, updating and deleting grocery shopping lists or grocery shopping list items. Shopping list items are supposed to have a name, item catagory, quantity, and price.

I could think of two options:

- Grid based layout

  **Advantage** Allows user to see more shopping list items

  **Disadvantage** Can't add any more attributes
- Multiple-row list based layout

  **Advantage** Allows user to add more attributes per item

  **Disadvantage** Number of visible rows decreases and leads to more scroll for user

Which one would you suggest?

Comment: Scrolling is of little worry on mobile. Since it's a grocery *list* app, my inclination would be to go the list route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a table.

Trying the different layouts helps to make it clear (I hope that these were what you meant, the descriptions were a bit ambiguous).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUeHBs.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The separate items are much harder to scan quickly.  Changing the order and adding up totals requires much more UI work (adding additional elements, deciding where they should go, etc).

The table based layout is easy to scan by running your eye *down* the list of items, easy to sort and easy to add totals.

For more info on table design check the [Ultimate guide to table UI patterns](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/ultimate-guide-to-table-ui-patterns/) and [Effective design of data tables](http://www.thinkui.co.uk/resources/effective-design-of-data-tables/#tables4).

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, one key info we are missing here is that we need to capture the info then and there rather than just show read-only list. It would mean that almost 90% of the line will be covered in text-boxes which will make scrolling (swiping) difficult.

Comment: While I think the type on these examples is way too small, I do like the point you are making in that the list/table is much easier to scan. @ripu1581 you're going to have to give us more details about this. Why would your screen be covered in text boxes? It sounds like you are maybe thinking more desktop than mobile with this.

Comment: if there is an image involved, an image which is easy to use for visual scanning (e.g., faces or vegetables or corporate logos anything else graphically distinctive), then the blocks might work better.  because then you can scan using the image and verify you are looking at the right thing using any other details in the block.

Comment: @DA01 The way I am visualizing Tims's answer is that if you choose to go with a grid based layout and try to put all the fields stacked horizontally with each other (name, catagory, quantity and price), it will result in 4 text-boxes in one line.

Comment: @joelarson Since I am entering the item name using text-boxes rather than selecting from a drop down, it would be difficult to find an image for the entered item name always. But I agree that I selecting from a set of items was an option, then Image would help in going with a multi-row based layout.

Comment: @ripu1581 I guess I don't quite understand. What do you mean 'stacked horizontally'? And by text box do you mean a text input field (form)?

Comment: @DA01 Yes. "stacked horizontally" means that there would be columns (like they are in a grid) and each column will have a text-input field.

Comment: @ripu1581 So you'd initially see a list of blank input fields? I'm not sure that's the best UI for a mobile app. You'd typically want a way to make a new item, but you wouldn't want the items, once made, to stay as input fields.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your items are not complex data, but list entries, I would use a row approach. The row approach also performs better with variable width of different devices and viewport orientations.

As user @DA01 pointed out in the comments, *if you make a list, why not use a list?*

It will feel most natural to use, because **the way you use a physical shopping list is putting items one after the other**, not drawing boxes of items on a table layout to fill the whole paper horizontally.